# How to programatically inject texts into a SWF file

Tags: flash

I'm using dynamic text fields in SWF and reading their values from an external text file, so that I'm able to use the same SWF "template" over and over again with different texts.
It would be great if would somehow wrap the SWF and variables file together into one SWF file programatically, so that I don't need to mess with two files per instance (or inject the texts and create a static SWF instance, as long as its done without manual intervention and the result is one SWF file, any solution is fine). 
It would be a real plus to be able to do this processing on my linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your external file is XML, it can be embedded in a class such as:

```
public class Data 
{ 
    [Embed(source='data.xml', mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
    public static const Xml:Class; 
}
```

...and then instantiated as:

```
var xml:XML = new XML(new Data.Xml);
```

Or, xml can be pasted into a class, such as:

```
public class Data
{

    public static var xml:XML = <root>
                                    <menu>
                                        <item>Waffles</item>
                                        <item>Belgian Waffles</item>
                                    </menu>
                                </root>;
}
```

At a higher level, it seems unnecessary to recompile a new SWF per template.

If each SWF were truly unique, text could be set in the file.  Having a single SWF able to accept a configuration file would make greater reuse of the template.

There are also approaches that use the mxmlc compiler on the server side.  This enables your server to automate complex build processes resulting in multiple SWFs.

Comment: This might be a trivial question but I'm a bit of a newbie - if I got the texts as you suggested into a Data class, how do I compile it programatically into the template SWF?

Comment: How are you currently programmatically compiling?  You would need to change the path to the XML document each pass from your build script.

Comment: I don't programatically compile ... I don't know how to do that, I'm just manually creating SWFs through GUI. But I now understand I can use the compiler from command line. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have a little open source project that let you insert text into SWF files. Perhaps it'll meet you needs. It's designed to get the text from GoogleDocs or a Word file stored in the public folder on DropBox. A local file would also work.

The code is written in PHP. You can see it in action here:

http://flaczkojad.blogspot.com/2012/05/introduction.html

A big caveat is that it only handles TLF text fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can Pass the Param from the Page
in Object Tag

```
<object width="180" height="60" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
<param name="movie" value="Your.swf" /> 
<param name="flashvars" value="text=YOUR TEXT" />
<embed width="180" height="60" bgcolor="#FFFFFF src="Your.swf" flashvars="text=YOUR TEXT" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" /> 
 </object>
```

& if your are using AS2 then just take it as:

```
varName=text;
```

Comment: In this specific scenario I do not control the page that calls the swf file, but thanks for the suggestion.